# Generating a specific Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matlab, numpy, matrix, symmetric

I want a fast method (one line, in python numpy or matlab) to generate a specific symmetric Matrix knowing it dimensions and a parameter `a`.

This matrix should have `1-a` on the diagonal and a elsewhere:

`1-a     a     a     a .......  a
  a     1-a    a   ...........  a
  a      a    1-a    a          a
  a                  .          .
  .                      .      .
  .                       1-a   a
  a .......................... 1-a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB you can do:

`a*ones(n,n) + (1-2*a)*diag(ones(n,1))`

where `n` is the size of your matrix.

If you can live with two lines, you could also do:

```
A = a*ones(n,n);
A(1:n+1:end) = 1-a; %this sets the diagonal entries
```

which I think is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

@Savithru has two excellent answers in Matlab. Here I just want to do it for fun....

EDIT: Surprisingly, `repmat` followed by `reshape` is actually faster than addition. In the following example, different methods, including Savithru's, are timed and compared.

```
n = 1e4;
a = 2;
timeit(@() reshape([repmat([1-a, a*ones(1,n)], 1,n-1),1-a], n,n))
timeit(@() a*ones(n,n) + (1-2*a)*eye(n))
timeit(@() a*ones(n,n) + (1-2*a)*diag(ones(n,1)))
timeit(@() testf(a,n))

function y = testf(a,n)
A = a*ones(n,n);
A(1:n+1:end) = 1-a;
y = A;
end


ans =

    0.7034


ans =

    1.0010


ans =

    1.0091


ans =

    0.4209
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numpy one liner

```
a = 0.7
n = 4

np.where(np.eye(n), 1-a, a)
# array([[0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3]])
```

If speed is a concern then I recommend

```
res = np.full((n, n), a)
np.einsum('ii->i', res)[:] = 1-a
res
# array([[0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7],
#        [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods below might not be 1 line, but they should be fast!

## method 1: create array with `np.ones` and fill with `fill_diagonal`

with `numpy`, you can use `np.ones` and [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html):

```
a = 5
size = 5

arr = np.ones((size,size)) * a
np.fill_diagonal(arr, a-1)

>>> arr
array([[4., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 4., 5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 4., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 4., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 4.]])
```

## method 2: fill the diagonal with `np.diag_indices` instead:

Alternatively, using `np.diag_indices`:

```
arr = np.ones((size,size)) * a
di = np.diag_indices(size)
arr[di] = a-1
```

## method 3: create array with `np.full`

You can also create the original array using `np.full` instead of `np.ones`:

```
arr = np.full((size,size), a)
np.fill_diagonal(arr, a-1)
# or:
# arr = np.full((size,size), a)
# np.fill_diagonal(arr, a-1)
```